# Make view stretch with animation when child is added

Tags: android, android-edittext, xamarin.android, xamarin

How can I make it so that when I add a child view into a view, the parent view stretches to be the required size for the new view. Presently, the app just pops to the required size, but I'd like it to grow.

How can I do this?

I want it to be a **gradual**, **animated transition**.

Comment: change parent to wrap_content

Comment: The parent is set to wrap_content, I've updated my question for better legibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation with applyTransformation.

```
Animation animation = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
                //some change views
            }
        };
```

Comment: This doesn't really help me at all. How can I make it so that when I add a child view, the parent view gradually increases in size to accommodate the child, rather than just instantly expanding?